# Что означает данное выражение " Which lambda can replace MySecret class?"

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

"Which lambda can replace MySecret class?"

```
    interface Secret{
      String test(String a, String b);
}

class MySecret implements Secret {
  public String test(String a, String b) {
         return a + b;
  }
}
```

- A) caller((a, b) -> a + b);
- B) caller((String a, b) -> a + b);
- C) caller((String a, String b) -> a + b);
- D) caller((a, b), a + b);
- E) caller((String a, b), String b), a + b);
- F) caller(String a, String b), a + b);

Мой вопрос не в том, как данное выражение переводится, а в том, что конкретно требуется сделать? И еще один вопрос, который не является отдельным вопросом, а основывается именно на только что заданном вопросе - откуда взялся caller(...) ?

А так дополнительно скажу - я знаю что лямбда работают через функциональные интерфейсы, но тут мне кажется, что вместо функционального интерфейса требуется функциональный класс, который в свою очередь как показано в тесте - имплементирует функциональный интерфейс. (Если я неправильно трактую содержимое  теста, пожалуйста - скорректируйте)

Comment: Требуется выбрать подходящие варианты из предложенных. Что такое `caller` и откуда он взялся, надо спрашивать у автора теста. Подозреваю, что это метод вызывающий переданную ему лямбду.

Comment: Ну так это ясно, что надо выбрать подходящий вариант, я это понимаю и могу сказать, что подходит для этого вариант С, не в этом дело, а в само выражении "заменить класс" и то речь не про анонимный класс, а класс, который вполне имеет имя, плюс к этому еще и имплементирует функциональный интерфейс.

Comment: До того, как лямбды появились в Java, вместо них использовались классы, реализующие _single method interface_, и не всегда при этом анонимные. Вы, похоже, опять "накручиваете себе голову".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev возможно и так, просто я новичок и пока мне трудно справится с лямбдами до конца, ну пожалуй это самая хлопотная тема для меня. Так как остальные темы довольно легко усвоил.

Comment: Почитайте "Лямбда-выражения в Java 8" Ричарда Уорбэртона. В ней просто и доходчиво эта тема описана.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Прочту. Если что, дам вам знать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Secret {
  String test(String a, String b);
}

public class Test {

  static void caller(Secret secret) {
    System.out.println(secret.test("test", "-shmest"));
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    caller((a, b) -> a + b);
  }

}
```

Comment: ответ ну на уровне моей логики понятен в данном куске кода. Но как будет выглядеть общий код задачи моего вопроса в итоге? (я новичок, если что, поэтому прошу понимания ^_^), ну хочу увидеть как работает в IDE, немного подебаггить, чтобы еще лучше понять.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan В ответе весь (общий?) код.

Comment: Если  я правильно понял, то public class Test  вполне тот же класс MySecret. Если да, то замену не вижу как то, ну то что требует задача. Но думаю, что тут есть какая то тонкость, которую я не вижу.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Поняли неправильно. `class Test` - это класс с методом `caller`. А явного класса, реализующего интерфейс `Secret` в коде вообще нет. Вместо него - лямбда `(a, b) -> a + b`, передающаяся в качестве параметра в вызов метода `caller` в методе `main`.

Comment: ладно, пожалуй все понятно.  Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из здравого смысла, всё, что нужно в этом вопросе это понимать - какая лямбда подходит и при этом синтаксически верна. Вот очень похожий вопрос из книги "Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide" (Jeanne Boyarsky, Scott Selikoff)

```
Which lambda can replace the MySecret class to return the same value? (Choose all that apply.)

public interface Secret {
  String magic(double d);
}

public class MySecret implements Secret {
  public String magic(double d) {
    return "Poof";
  }
}

A. caller((e) -> "Poof");
B. caller((e) -> {"Poof"});
C. caller((e) -> { String e = ""; "Poof" });
D. caller((e) -> { String e = ""; return "Poof"; });
E. caller((e) -> { String e = ""; return "Poof" });
F. caller((e) -> { String f = ""; return "Poof"; });
```

В приведённом изначально вопросе уж очень странные варианты ответов.
По поводу корректного синтаксиса, всё написано в документации. Если коротко, то в целом лямбда выглядит так:

```
(параметры) -> {тело}
```

при этом (по памяти)

- если параметр один и тип не указан, то скобки можно опустить;
- если параметров несколько, то скобки обязательны;
- если тип указан, то скобки обязательны;
- если тип указан для хотя бы одного параметра, то должен быть указан для всех;
- если одно выражение в теле, то фигурные скобки, слово return, точку с запятой можно опустить (можно, но не обязательно), но только всё сразу;
- если в теле несколько выражений, то должны присутствовать и фигурные скобки, и слово return, и точка с запятой после каждого выражений, в том числе после return

Comment: Есть ли такой список, статья, или видео где описаны все синтаксически корректные виды вызовов лямбд? Мне лично попадались одни вызовы методов функциональных интерфейсов через лямбд, или просто замена конструкции анонимного класса на лямбду, но замена класса, у которого есть имя и одновременно имплементация - я не встречал. ну или вообще про все виды лямбд и правильное их использование.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan я отредактировал ответ на бегу и описал лямбды, но всё же обратитесь к документации

Comment: да я это заметил, просто то что вы описали я читал вчера в одном из сайтов предложенных гуглом, и это вроде не совсем то, что мешает мне понять как правильно относится к задачам схожих по содержанию задаче описанного в моем вопросе. А так спасибо за совет. Документацию поизучаю пока.